# Where is Update Manager in Xubuntu 13.04?

Tags: updates, xubuntu, update-manager

Update Manager doesn't work in Xubuntu 13.04.

When the system loads a notice appears "There are 96 updates, click this note to update". I click a notice but nothing happens, it just disappears.

I read their site: http://xubuntu.org/upgrading/

> Open Applications->System->Update Manager.

But there is no any `Update Manager` in `System`.

Where to find `Update Manager` or how to enable it?

Answer (score 9):

Go to: Applications Menu -> Settings Manager -> Software Updater

Answer (score 3):

You might want to install the Update Manager prior to use. 
Run in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install update-manager
```

After a successful install, you will be able to find it in the menu also.

```
Applications -> Settings -> Software Updater
```